# Probability of certain event

Tags: probability

I need help with the following question:

You are participating among other 9 participants to get a scholarship.
What is the probability of win if there are two scholarship?

I am absolutely sure that if were just one scholarship the answer must be 10%
But in this case how to calculate?

Comment: How many ways to randomly pick two numbers among 1 to 10 if one of the number is 1?

Comment: Hmmm... I gues there are 9 ways, because you already fix 1 so it remains 9 other numbers to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$10$ people are compitting over two scholarships. The first scholarship can be granted to any of the $10$ participants; the second scholarship to any of the remaining $9$ participants. So there are $10*9=90$ possible combinations of winners.

Of those $90$ possible cases, how many involve **you** winning the scholarship? There are two outcomes to consider.

$a)$ Let's suppose you are given the first scholarship. Then there's $9$ other people that could win the other one, so $9$ possible ressults.

$b)$If you are given the second scolarship, then the first one could have been given to any of the other $9$ people also. So there are $9$ possible results here too.

In total $9+9=18$ possible cases in which you win the scholarship. Of all $90$ cases, this is $\frac{18}{90}*100=20$% of chances of getting the scholarship.

If you think about it it makes sense that, if $1$ scolarship implies a $10$% chances of winning it, the double amount of scholarships (given to the same amount of people) implies the double chances of winning.

¡Saludos!

Comment: I was thinking in the way you said "If you think about it it makes sense that, if 1 scolarship implies a 10% chances of winning it, the double amount of scholarships (given to the same amount of people) implies the double chances of winning" . But I didn't know how to justify. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay problema! Si esto fue una solución correcta por favor márcalo, de modo que tu pregunta no aparezca en la etiqueta de "Sin responder". Pero sólo si considerás que tu duda ha sido resuelta. Sin más, ¡saludos!

Answer (score 0):

There is a $\frac{1}{10}$ chance of winning the first scholarship and a $\frac{9}{10}$ chance of not winning the first scholarship. Nine participants compete for a second scholarship so the probability of winning the second scholarship, given that you didn't win the first scholarship is $\frac{1}{9}$. Therefore, the probability of winning the second scholarship is $\frac{9}{10}\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{10}$ and the probability of not winning any scholarship is $\frac{9}{10}\frac{8}{9}=\frac{8}{10}$.

Since we cannot win both the first and second scholarship our total chances of winning one are $\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{2}{10}=\frac{1}{5}$